# Trying to statically link MYSQL library in C++ without any luck

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

I'm stuck on this issue and I don't think it should be this difficult. I'm essentially getting a compilation error with several 'undefined reference' warnings which are, I believe, caused by the library not being properly linked to the project.

The library resources along with the required header files are all located in the include folder of my project as well as in the include path. (For reference, I'm working inside of VScode).

Here's part of my makefile

```
MYSQL_CONCPP_DIR = /home/me/Git/CppProject/include/cpp-connector-mysql
UTILS_DIR = /home/me/Git/CppProject/include/utils/
CPPFLAGS = -DSTATIC_CONCPP -I $(UTILS_DIR) 
LDLIBS = $(MYSQL_CONCPP_DIR)/lib64/libmysqlcppconn8-static.a -I $(UTILS_DIR) -lssl -lcrypto -lpthread
CXXFLAGS    := -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -g
```

I started moving towards C++ development maybe a week ago and have been programming for maybe half a year. So, if there is something obvious that I am missing I would not mind being embarrassed on Stack Overflow, as long as I learn something.

I've scoured the internet to find a solution and nothing has worked. I successfully did the exact same thing I'm trying to do (connect to localhost via a User class and a Connector class) in both Java and Python in a few hours, but am stuck on C++ with this issue.

Here's the actual error message I get, which is incredibly difficult to decipher:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: src/Connector.o: in function `check_lib()':
/home/adis/Git/CppProject/include/cpp-connector-mysql/jdbc/cppconn/driver.h:77: undefined reference to `check(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/adis/Git/CppProject/include/cpp-connector-mysql/jdbc/cppconn/driver.h:78: undefined reference to `check(std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > const&)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: src/Connector.o: in function `get_driver_instance_by_name':
/home/adis/Git/CppProject/include/cpp-connector-mysql/jdbc/cppconn/driver.h:90: undefined reference to `_get_driver_instance_by_name'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: src/Connector.o: in function `mysqlx::abi2::r0::string::traits<char>::to_str[abi:cxx11](mysqlx::abi2::r0::string const&)':
/home/adis/Git/CppProject/include/cpp-connector-mysql/mysqlx/devapi/common.h:225: undefined reference to `mysqlx::abi2::r0::string::Impl::to_utf8[abi:cxx11](mysqlx::abi2::r0::string const&)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: src/Connector.o: in function `mysqlx::abi2::r0::DbDoc::DbDoc()':
/home/adis/Git/CppProject/include/cpp-connector-mysql/mysqlx/devapi/document.h:107: undefined reference to `vtable for mysqlx::abi2::r0::DbDoc'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: src/Connector.o: in function `mysqlx::abi2::r0::DbDoc::~DbDoc()':
/home/adis/Git/CppProject/include/cpp-connector-mysql/mysqlx/devapi/document.h:81: undefined reference to `vtable for mysqlx::abi2::r0::DbDoc'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: src/Connector.o: in function `mysqlx::abi2::r0::Value::print(std::ostream&) const':
/home/adis/Git/CppProject/include/cpp-connector-mysql/mysqlx/devapi/document.h:508: undefined reference to `mysqlx::abi2::r0::common::Value::print(std::ostream&) const'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: src/Connector.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTCN6mysqlx4abi22r05ValueE0_NS1_6common5ValueE[_ZTVN6mysqlx4abi22r05ValueE]+0x18): undefined reference to `typeinfo for mysqlx::abi2::r0::common::Value'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: src/Connector.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTCN6mysqlx4abi22r05ValueE0_NS1_6common5ValueE[_ZTVN6mysqlx4abi22r05ValueE]+0x20): undefined reference to `mysqlx::abi2::r0::common::Value::print(std::ostream&) const'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: src/Connector.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN6mysqlx4abi22r05ValueE[_ZTIN6mysqlx4abi22r05ValueE]+0x28): undefined reference to `typeinfo for mysqlx::abi2::r0::common::Value'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:76: main] Error 1
```

Comment: Rip, had same problem and tried all the solutions on stack overflow, but had no luck. Resolved to using C version of mysql.

Comment: @Asphodel Yeah I am close to doing this as well. It's a shame since I wanted to practice Object Oriented design in C++ and the program has never even compiled lol.

Comment: I couldn't get C++ Connector working, so I'm using the native MySQL C library.  After too many hours of debugging and changing C++ Connector, I gave up.

Comment: According to [this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/8.0/en/connector-cpp-introduction.html), you may have better luck using Visual C++ and Visual Studio.  I see "MSVC" mentioned several times.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yup, I noticed that too. Guess I'll just bite the bullet and do this thing in msvc if nobody else has a solution, seems like there are a lot of people encountering the same issue but never resolving it.

Comment: If it works under Visual Studio, probably a case of only testing under VS, and then just throwing in g++ as a "not tested.  Try at your own risk" kind of scenario.  Those look like linker errors, so g++ actually did compile the code without errors.  The problem is that whether what you compiled, given those compile switches, actually compiled the source required for proper linkage.